# Angular 7 - call directive on function

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, customvalidator

I have two dates input - "start date" and "end date" - 
I also have two directives in which I am using as validators - the allowed minimum and the allowed maximum value for each field (so that the start date won't be later from the end date). 
If for example I change the start date to be later than the end date, the validator will alert that it is not valid. 
when I change the end date to a later date from the start date - this alert will not disappear since I haven't triggered the "customMax" validator. 
how can I trigger both validators at once on every change in one of the fields?

Thanks,

inputs HTML:

```
<input
type="text" class="form-control"
name="startDate{{d.index}}"
required
[customMax]="d.endDate"
(dateChange)="onDateChange('startDate', d.index, $event)"
[(ngModel)]="d.startDate"
appMyDatePicker>
<input type="text" class="form-control"
required
[customMin]="d.startDate"
name="endDate{{d.index}}"
(dateChange)="onDateChange('endDate', d.index, $event)"
[(ngModel)]="d.endDate"
appMyDatePicker>
```

customMax directive:

```
@Directive({
selector: '[appCustomMaxValidator],[customMax][ngModel]',
providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: 
CustomMaxValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class CustomMaxValidatorDirective implements Validator {

@Input()
customMax: Date;
constructor() { }

validate(c: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
const maxDateConvertInit = moment(this.customMax, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log('cant be greater than:' + maxDateConvertInit);
const maxDateConvertCompare = moment(c.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
console.log('check date:' + maxDateConvertCompare);
const testScore = (maxDateConvertInit <= maxDateConvertCompare) ? {'customMax': true} : null;
return testScore;
}
}
```

customMin Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomMinValidator],[customMin][ngModel]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomMinValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class CustomMinValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  @Input()
  customMin: Date;
  constructor() { }

  validate(c: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    const minDateConvertInit = moment(this.customMin, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    const minDateConvertCompare = moment(c.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    const testScore = (minDateConvertInit >= minDateConvertCompare) ? {'customMin': true} : null;
    return testScore;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this should be handled by your component. You should trigger markAsTouched:

https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsTouched

on both of the FormControls once one of them changes. This should force the validators to re-calculate. In my apps I use the following service:

```
import {Injectable, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class FormService {

 constructor() {}

 public handleInvalidControls(form: NgForm, changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.markInvalidControlsAsTouched(form);
    changeDetector.detectChanges();
 }

 private markInvalidControlsAsTouched(form: NgForm) {
     for (const key in form.form.controls) {
        const control = form.form.controls[key];
        if (control instanceof FormControl && control.invalid) {
           control.markAsTouched();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

In order to access your form from your component, you need to use Angulars [ViewChild decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) in your template:

```
<form #submitForm="ngForm">
```

and in your component:

```
@Injectable()
export class FormComponent {

    @ViewChild('submitForm')
    submitForm;    
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you add your HTML template? I can't access my form tag from the ts file.